# select all method for checkboxes , should not select disabled checbox in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

i have a list with checkboxes in the table , when i click select all function , it selects all checkbox including disabled ones, i neeed to exclude the disabled checkbox .

```
      <li><a @click.prevent="selectAll" id="cardSelectAllAId"> 
        SelectAll</a></li>

      <single-checkbox class="checkbox "
                 inputId="card.data.id"
                     v-if="card.data.id"
             @change="change(card.data)"
             :value="card.data.selected"
        :disabled="!card.data.licenseEnabled">



      selectAll() {
       for (let i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i += 1) {
        if (this.cards[i].selected !== undefined) {
         this.cards[i].selected = true;
        }
      },
```

Comment: What have you tried? It should be as simple as changing your if condition to something like `if(this.cards[i].selected !== undefined && this.cards[i].licenceEnabled)`. Also, your logic uses `card[i]` but in the template it is used as `card.data` where is `card` coming from in the template?

Comment: cards comes frome the data source props . this condition didnt work , i tried before

Comment: i tried by getting the class name and check if it is disabled or not

Comment: Understood. Does each card item have a `data` field? Another small thing to note: It's probably a bad idea to mutate incoming props form inside the child component. There is probably a better way to do this

Comment: yes it does have data

Comment: then it probably should be `if(this.cards[i].data.selected !== undefined && this.cards[i].data.licenceEnabled)`

Comment: we have  to unselect for the checkbox if  this.cards[i].licenceEnabled  is false. so we should not change the condition , i guess , its in the function statement we need to include a function to remove the selection

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your function-

```
  // Reset all selected first
  this.cards.map((x) => x.selected = false);
  // Filter and then set selected to true
  this.cards
    .filter((x) => x.data.licenseEnabled)
    .map((x) => x.selected = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(this.cards[i].selected !== undefined && this.cards[i].licenseEnabled)
```

this works